# Nested for loops to compare elements

Tags: class, python-3.x, methods

I have to write a function that returns how many circles are 'alone' meaning not touching any other circle. All circles are contained within a list called `self.__`.

I already have a function called `overlaps(aCircle)` that returns True if it does overlap another circle, and None if it doesnt. So basically I have to check if a circle in a list is overlapping another circle in that same list, and if it returns None than it means it is 'alone'.

I cant seem to understand how I would iterate over that same list twice whilst not comparing if a circle is overlapping itself because that will always return `True`.

Comment: You could use a pair of indices (e.g. `current` and `compare`) and do e.g. `if current != compare and overlaps(circles[current], circles[compare])`, or allow the instances to be compared for equality directly, or...

Answer (score 0):

Using Python's itertools, you can iterate over all possible pairs of circles in your list. This has the added benefit that if you've already compared A with B, you don't end up recomparing B with A.

```
from itertools import combinations
for circle1, circle2 in combinations(self.__, 2):
    if circle1.overlaps(circle2):
        # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

If your circle values in the list are distinct then this should suffice.

```
for c1 in range(len(self.__)):
    for c2 in range(len(self.__)):
        if c2 < c1: #If prevents comparison twice thanks to Terry Jan Reedy's suggestion
            circle1 = self._[c1]
            circle2 = self._[c2]
            #check if circle overlaps using circle1 and circle2
```

Otherwise use `enumerate` to track which item is being checked

```
for c1, circle1 in enumerate(self.__):
    for c2, circle2 in enumerate(self.__):
        if c2 < c1: #If prevents comparison twice thanks to Terry Jan Reedy's suggestion
            #check if circle overlaps using circle1 and circle2
```

Comment: This does each comparison twice.  To avoid that, limit the inner loop to indexes c2 less than c1:  `for c2 in range(c1):` followed by `circle2 = self.__[c2]`.  This is standard technique for iterating over the off-diagonal lower triangle of a matrix.

Comment: Updated answer. Thanks for the info, I completely forgot about the double comparison, and that's a good method around it I wasn't aware of.